# Installing Facebook PHP SDK via Composer w/ Autoload

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, composer-php

I have followed the instructions at getcomposer.org combined with those at developers.facebook.com but I am struggling to get the PHP SDK up and running.

The install worked fine and all files were generated including the autoload.php in the vendor folder.

I have put this line in my index.php:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

When I call `FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('YOUR_APP_ID', 'YOUR_APP_SECRET');` I am getting a fatal error, CLASS 'FacebookSession' not found.

What do I need to do?

I guess it is something with path names and autoload.php but I can't figure it out.

Vendor folder is at root with index.php.

Comment: import the `FacebookSession` class. Add `use Facebook\FacebookSession;` to your file.

Comment: I may be being totally naive, but isn't the purpose of using autoload.php to load write all the use statements?  I'm new to this so please explain further if you don't mind.

Comment: This worked.  Without fully understanding how PHP works, I would never have gotten this.  Facebook Docs are quite misleading too.

Comment: @GavinMcBride Yeah, this one's not your fault. Blame Facebook's docs for neglecting to mention this in the "getting started" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `use` keyword does not include or autoload. It only tells PHP to import the specified namespace to the current scope which has been autoload-ed in this case with composer.

Have you tried to add `use Facebook\FacebookSession;` (at the beginning of your PHP file after the `require vendor/autoload.php` line) as [xurshid29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29013707/installing-facebook-php-sdk-via-composer-w-autoload#comment46274929_29013707) commented?

Comment: This is unfortunately the fault of Facebook omitting that very important step in the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

Comment: Yours is not appearing as an answer to accept.  It says there is only one answer.